# width:100vw of element breaks position: sticky

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stretch a sticky element to size of the screen. I have the following HTML

```css
.large {
  height: 200vw;
  width: 200vw;
}

.header {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color:white;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>

<div class="large">Content</div>
```

The problem is that this works but the element is not stretched. If I change    `width:100px` to  `width:100vw` the sticky to the left breaks. So it seems like I cannot specify relative width and use sticky to the left at the same time?

Comment: A div is not a self closing tag.. Should be `<div></div>`

Comment: @ninadepina that is not the problem, the code in the sandbox still runs, just the width is not correct

Comment: That is the problem tho.. with your tags it doesn't work, when using the html tags properly it does work

Comment: @ninadepina, i have tried it with some content in the div, and then it also isn't sticky for me with width:100vw.

Comment: Oh it should be, just as in the answer below. Does that work for you?

Comment: @ninadepina No, if I scroll the right, the bar moves to the left, it should stick to the left.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Why does the `.large` need to be `200vw`?

Comment: @ninadepina, because I want to simulate an element that is larger than the screen but keep the header sticky to the top and the left. My header is actually a subheader that moves on top of the actual header in my app but here it is the the only header, so it is a bit weird that I want to use sticky but it makes sense when there is another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a `div` around both elements and giving that `div` a `display: inline-block;`:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.large {
  height: 200vw;
  width: 200vw;
}

.header {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="large"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the `.container` could be the `body` itself

Comment: This is correct for pure html. Thanks! I am using Tailwindcss as well, which kind of breaks the sticky part.

Comment: @ninadepina could you explain why the inline block is necessary?